# How can I loop through a string array and only get the value of the data attribute that is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get from the `<ul class="click-to-section">` to the `tester` class where I want to loop over the children that has `data-section` and only show it if it matches up with the `<ul class="click-to-section">`

See the screenshot of the HTML from Google Dev tools - https://ibb.co/Y3g1jmC

my code to show this is below:

```
$(".click-to-section li").click(function() {
    $(this).each(function(){
    let testdata = $(this).data('section');
                            
   let testdata2 = $(this).closest("main").next().next().children();
   $(testdata2).each(function(){
       const dataSection = $(this).data("section");
       console.log(dataSection);
   });
 });  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="click-to-section">
        <li data-section="videos">Videos</li> **When this is clicked**
        <li data-section="lo">Learning objectives</li>
        <li data-section="credits">Credit</li>
        <li data-section="toolkits">Toolkit</li>
    </ul>

<div class="opinions"></div>
<div class="tester"> **Needs to traverse to this div and loop through the children to show the sections one at a time based on the data-section in the ul menu to equal the data-section here **
    <div data-section="credits" class="js-tabs" style="display: none;"</div>
    <section data-section="videos" class="js-tabs"></section>
    <div class="js-tabs" data-section="lo" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div data-section="toolkits" class="js-tabs" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your HTML as well?

Comment: @Tushar the HTML is in the link on the description. The actual website is built in wordpress so it's component based, but you can easily see the HTML structure in the link provided https://ibb.co/Y3g1jmC

Comment: If you are looking for favorable feedback and a potential answer to your question, you should place your HTML in the question as properly formatted HTML, please do not add an image with the HTML.

Comment: @dalelandry I can't paste the HTML as it is generated using WordPress. The layout from wordpress is what is generated in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the code to click on li and show tester elements that matches data attributes of clicked li

**Working Code below**

```js
$(".click-to-section li").on("click", function() {
  var dataSection = $(this).attr("data-section");
  $(".tester > *").hide();
  $(".tester [data-section=" + dataSection + "]").show();
})
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="click-to-section">
  <li data-section="videos">Videos</li> **When this is clicked**
  <li data-section="lo">Learning objectives</li>
  <li data-section="credits">Credit</li>
  <li data-section="toolkits">Toolkit</li>
</ul>

<div class="opinions"></div>
<div class="tester">
  <div data-section="credits" class="js-tabs">cred </div>
  <section data-section="videos" class="js-tabs">video</section>
  <div class="js-tabs" data-section="lo">lo</div>
  <div data-section="toolkits" class="js-tabs">js tabs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy but this is not what I want. See the added HTML in the post

Comment: so do you want to show the tester element that matches the data section with ul li when you click on li?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted. I guess I was getting stuck on the second bit to use the loop which was not needed. Appreciate your help. I i will mark this as top answer

Comment: thanks can you up vote as well once you get a chance?

Comment: because I am new on here, it does not let me up vote.. sorry